# Best Sorting algorithm for 1000 Integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Interview question-
Which among the following will be the best to sort an array of 1000 INTEGERS.
1. Quick Sort
2.Tim Sort
3. Merge Sort
4. Counting sort.

I chose quick sort,but i guess thats wrong. Can anyone tell what's the right answer and how?

Comment: That depends on lots of contraints, are you allowed to use extra space ? Do you have to provide the best case,worst case or average case ?

Comment: Umm... well the question was just this much.

Comment: @user2946079 Most interviewers will look for you to ask those kinds of clarifying questions before diving in to answer.

Comment: The answer is whatever the standard library gives you. Unless you really, really need this 1000 integer sort to be blazing fast, there's no reason to complicate this part of your code.

Comment: @MooseBoys it was a written test. Not face-to-face one.

Answer (score 1):

Timsort is usually the best algorithm.  It use heuristic to decide which sort algorithm should be used (merge or insertion sort). Counting sort only will be a good option if the diference between max and minimum is small. Quicksort can be O(n^2 ) in some cases.

Worst case of Timsort is O (n log n) but in best case is O (n).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the quickest that would be, Merge Sort.

Comment: Why not counting sort?

Comment: Because Merge sort's worst case complexity is O(n log n)

Comment: Counting sort uses key values as indexes into an array, it is not a comparison sort, and the Ω(n log n) lower bound for comparison sorting does not apply to it.

Comment: @Unkn0wn.Bit   Are you suggesting to keep 2^31-1 slots available for the counts?  The OP did not mention anything about the range of the ints being constrained

Comment: In the case of not caring about space complexity, Merge sort offers a good choice.

Comment: Have you considered sort algorithm of Tim Peppers (Timsort)? It is O(n) for average case and O(n log n) in worst case.

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't consider that, but, first it is O(n) for the best case, not average case. Second, talking about time complexity, you should assume you would face the worst case in which they both are O(n log n), so ... not much difference.

Answer (score 0):

for `1000` integers the space complexity should not matter that hence `mergesort` is the best because it give `O(nlogn)` whereas quicksort gives worst case `O(n^2)` . Counting sort assumes that integers are in particular range which is not the case in your question. I might as well refer `bubble sort` for that matter because of small input size and its ease of coding.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Performance) entry for Timsort, it would be the 'best' on real-world data.

I tried to reproduce the table here, but my foo is lacking.

The following table compares the time complexity of timsort with other comparison sorts.

```
               Timsort     Merge       Quicksort    Insertion   Selection   Smoothsort
Best case      O(n)        O(n log n)  O(n log n)   O(n)        O(n^2)      O(n)
Average case   O(n log n)  O(n log n)  O(n log n)   O(n^2)      O(n^2)      O(n log n)
Worst case     O(n log n)  O(n log n)  O(n^2)       O(n^2)      O (n^2)     O(n log n)
```

`Where O is theta.`

I don't know how [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) compares.

Comment: Counting sort O(n + k) where k is size of range. In this case O(2^32 -1 + 1000).  Another point is Quicksort is faster than Mergesort in average case.